# Make Python module available for all Linux users

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-18.04, faker

I have a Python 2.7 question, if somebody can help.
When we install a Python module using pip, how do we make it available to all users? Please, see the example below (with module faker). The import works when I am root, but doesn’t work when I am ubuntu user.
I have already tried to install using option --system, and also changing umask, as recommended in some articles I have found. Didn’t work so far. Any ideas?
If we run "which python", both users point to the same one.

```
root@ip-172-30-244-157:/home/ubuntu# 
root@ip-172-30-244-157:/home/ubuntu# python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Sep 30 2020, 13:38:04) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import faker
>>> 
>>> exit()
root@ip-172-30-244-157:/home/ubuntu# 
root@ip-172-30-244-157:/home/ubuntu# 
root@ip-172-30-244-157:/home/ubuntu# exit
exit
ubuntu@ip-172-30-244-157:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-30-244-157:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-30-244-157:~$ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Sep 30 2020, 13:38:04) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import faker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named faker
>>>
```

Comment: Could you run this as root: `python -c 'import faker; print faker.__file__'` ?

Comment: root@ip-172-30-244-157:/home/ubuntu# python -c 'import faker; print faker.__file__'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/faker/__init__.pyc

Comment: what happens when you run @GeorgesMartin command from the ubuntu user?

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-30-244-157:~$ python -c 'import faker; print faker.__file__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named faker

Comment: You must consider using `virtualenv`. Have you tried `pip install fake --user ubuntu`?

Comment: Ok, I solved the issue. I will post the solution shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the issue.
In my case, the problematic module was "faker". But, when we install the faker, another additional module is installed as well (in this case - text-unidecode).
Then I uninstalled both modules, ran "umask 022" and re-installed the faker.
This solved the issue for all other users.
Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Great :-) These bug reports may be of interest to you: [Install locations and features missed on Debian](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2232) and [Debian-specific behavior lost when Setuptools adopts distutils](https://github.com/pypa/distutils/issues/2)